# .htaccess Rewrite Engine ON, show no_image.png in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

In order to show `no_image.png` by **.htaccess** (if image does not exist) I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /images/no_image.png [L]
```

However,  this do not resolve images in the following URL format:

```
www.domain.com/t.php?src=p/dd5e5b08_1.jpg
```

I would like to show `no_image.png` trough **.htaccess** if no image detected in  the sample URL above 
Please provide solution and thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `REQUEST_URI` ends in `t.php`, not an image extension, since the query string isn't part of the URI and is thus not being inspected by your rewrite rules. You should use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to inspect the query string.

If the url was `http://www.domain.com/p/dd5e5b08_1.jpg` and `/p/dd5e5b08_1.jpg` didn't exist on the server you would get `/images/no_image.png` instead with your current rules.

That said, it looks like you are using PHP to load the images, in which case it would be appropriate to use PHP to determine if the file exists and serve the default if it doesn't, not the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` doesn't include `QUERY_STRING` part of your URL, so your `.htaccess` rules are not applying on this. I see you are calling images via a php script so I would advice you to check if this image file exists in your php script and if not you redirect or write out no_image.png contents.

simple code for t.php:

```
<?php

if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$_GET["src"])) {
  header("Location:".$_GET["src"]);
} else {
  header("Location:/images/no_image.png");
}

?>
```

or you can also `echo` contents of image file using `header('Content-Type: image/png')`